# How to design Tree structured mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking for an easy way to define my mongoose.js in Express models like TREE nodes ( categories, classifications ) with children and parent dynamic references?

[image]

MongoDB explained a way to work with tree models in MONGO but I didn't find anything for querying with "mongoose"

mongo Example: https://mongoing.com/docs/tutorial/model-tree-structures.html

Comment: What in particular wasn't clear in https://mongoing.com/docs/tutorial/model-tree-structures.html ?

Comment: You probably want to see how to [query it](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) and not just define it?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, it is, but I don't know how to define the Schema like that in Mongoose and query it :) I'm new to mongoDB, if you can just show me an example of mongoose.Schema file

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate-graphLookup - maybe add the schema (from the mongodb turoial example) and ask how to query it recursively? (like, how do I get the children up to depth 3 or some other tree query you're asking about). Currently the question is pretty vague regarding what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum i need to have both child and parent referneces dynamicly, so i can render trees easily

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum the query part is really easier, because we have Populate method in mongoose, but defining in mongoose for recursive and dynamic reference is hard for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216736/discussion-between-tafhim-and-benjamin-gruenbaum).

Comment: Hello, can pls add the schema ?